# Advanced Search Feature: Order results by Newest, Votes or Active

Tags: feature-request, search

When searching on SO, I really don't care about the "Relevance" tab.  I much prefer the "Newest" or "Active" tabs.

I would like to be able to search either by "Newest", "Votes" or "Active" results, without having to click another tab after searching.  You can call me lazy, but I prefer "efficient".

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
[industry-standard] results:newest
```

or

```
[industry-standard] results:votes
```

or

```
[industry-standard] results:active
```

If no "results:" option is specified, then it would continue to search using the "Relevance" tab as default, since that's how it behaves now.

I hope this hasn't been asked already, but with so many questions just being titled "Advanced search features", I may have missed a duplicate.

Comment: I thought clicking is more easier than writing.

Comment: I dunno, I can type really fast, and I rather cut out the middle man and skip right to the results I want.

Comment: why not both? make the middle man run an advanced search and select relevance as default criteria if nothing is entered

Comment: @LBT as I read it right now you are asking for a search reform, removing "Relevance" and making users type more for the same results when using the middle man... ;)